# How do i compare and verify the content of a website hosted in two different environments are same?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a website which is hosted in two different environments say internal & public. I want to validate the contents shown to the public is the same as the internal environment. Is there any tool to verify this or how do we do using Selenium?

Comment: Not sure what is your requirement but one approach would be capturing screenshots of the different environment and compare them for a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate the whole content of the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('PAGE1URL')
page1Content = driver.page_source  # you can store it in a variable or a txt file

driver.get('PAGE2URL')
page2Content = driver.page_source

if(page1Content == page2Content):
    print("Content validation successful")
```